# How to change/delete string using php called page?

Tags: php, html, html-parsing

I'm using the current function :

```
function callframe(){
    $ch = curl_init("file.html");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    echo curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
}
```

Then i call callframe() and it appears on my php page. 
Let's say this is the file.html content :

```
<html>
<body>

   [...]

<td class="bottombar" valign="middle" height="20" align="center" width="1%" nowrap> 

   [...]

<a href="link.html">Link</a>

   [...]

</body>
</html>
```

- How could i delete the  `<td class="bottombar" valign="middle" height="20" align="center" width="1%" nowrap>` line?
- How could i delete one parameter like the height parameter, or change align center to left?
- How could i insert 'http://www.whatever.com/' before link.html in my a href

Thanks for your help!

ps: you may want to ask why i don't directly change file.html. well, then, there would be no question.

Comment: You need to get an HTML parser that can manipulate your HTML documents.  Do not try to use regular expressions for this task or you will be sorry down the road.  You cannot reliably parse HTML with regular expressions, and you will face sorrow and frustration down the road. As soon as the HTML changes from your expectations, your code will be broken. See http://htmlparsing.com/php for examples of how to properly parse HTML with PHP modules that have already been written, tested and debugged.

Comment: Have a look at [`DOMDocument`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php)/[`DOMElement`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domelement.php)/[`DOMNode`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domnode.php) documentation. Everything you need is most likely in PHP natively (unless you're using a different build of course).

Answer (score 1):

To get you started, instead of just echoing the `curl_exec`, store it first so you can work with it:

```
$html = curl_exec($ch);
```

now, load it up in to a [`DOMDocument`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) that you can then use for parsing and making changes:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html);
```

now, for the first task (removing that line) it'd look something like:

```
//
// rough example, not just copy-paste code
//

$tds = $dom->getElementsByTagname('td'); // $tds = DOMNodeList
foreach ($tds as $td) // $td = DOMNode
{
    // validate this $td is the one you want to delete, then
    // call something like:
    $parent = $td->parentNode;
    $parent->removeChild($td);
}
```

*Perform any other kinds of processing as well.*

Then, finally call:

```
echo $dom->saveHTML();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can take your output in one variable and can use string functions to do your stuffs

```
function callframe(){
 $ch = curl_init("file.html");
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
 $result = curl_exec($ch);
 $result = str_replace("link.html","http://www.whatever.com/link.html", $result);
 // other replacements as required
 curl_close($ch);
}
```

Comment: it seems that curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); is not working. The page don't load. :(

Answer (score 0):

This is how i did it.
To change for example an option field (for search string)
This change the second value of my option list and replace it with what i wanted.

```
require('simple_html_dom.php');

$html = file_get_html('fileorurl');

$e = $html->find('option', 0) ->next_sibling ();
$e->outertext = '<option value="WTR">Tradition</option>';
```

then 
echo $html;